# Two Sum with duplicates

Tags: arrays, list, sum

I've been looking at the Two Sum problem:

> Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

and am confused about the variation where duplicates are allowed. Why is it if there are duplicates that it is a problem? Can we not just return the the index of the duplicate as well?

Comment: Did you forget to mention what the duplicate variation is?

Comment: this question seems to be a better fit for https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5):

To clarify for others, the "duplicate variation" is simply what you'd expect: numbers may be repeated within the array.

This doesn't matter if you write a brute force algorithm.

But the usual non-brute-force algorithm involves hashing the numbers to their indices (*i.e.* creating a reverse array). This way, given a target `T`, one checks whecks whether `T - Array[0]` exists as a hash key (in which case, the solution has been found), and if not, continues to `T - Array[1]`, and so on.

Now, the above works if all numbers are unique. If numbers can be duplicated however, there is this case for example:

```
Array[] = {1, 3, 4, 4, 6, 8};
T = 8;
```

The hash must contain a one-to-many mapping for 4. So it involves making sure you don't accidentally create a sum out of the same element twice, *e.g.*

```
Array[2] + Array[2]
```

Comment: Here is a great overview of that problem, https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs9/lectures/06/TwoSum.pdf, explaining this in another way, in case my explanation wasn't sufficient.

Comment: But the solution provided doesn't seem to account for duplicates. It's still a hash map/table. Meaning it will just overwrite previous keys.

Comment: You can make the key the number and the value the number of times you have seen it.

Answer (score -3):

With duplicates not allowed this should work

```
class Solution:
def twoSum(self, nums, target):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :type target: int
    :rtype: List[int]
    """
    nums_l = len(nums);
    for i in range(0,nums_l):
        for j in range(0,nums_l):
            if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target and i != j):
                return [i,j];
```

A slight modification can be made to the if statement to allow duplicates.